# Matlab Finite Difference Method beam deflection

Tags: matlab

When I run the code, it shows 'Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements.' How to solve this kind of problem? Can someone explain about this? thank you~
Problem of code is in finding RHS

---

```
clear;
clc;
close all;

%%% Data Input
L = 2;
I = 200000;
E = 2000000000
EI = E * I;

%%% Uniform Loading, w 
w = 20000;

N = 6;
dx = L/(N-1);
%%% Discretize the bar
x = linspace(0,L,N)

u = zeros(1,N)

%%% Boundary conditions
u(1) = 0;
u(end) = 0;

%u_unknowns = u(2:end-1)


%%% u(i+1)-2*u(i)+U(i-1) = ((L-x)*w*x*dx^2)/2*EI
p = (w.*x).*(L-x).*(dx^2)/2.*EI
% if i = 2
% u(3)-2u(2)+u(1) = ((L-x)*w*x*dx^2)/2*EI
% u(4)-2u(3)+u(2) = ((L-x)*w*x*dx^2)/2*EI

%f = ones(nx,1)*w.*x.*(L-x).*(dx^2)/2*EI;
%%% RHS
RHS = zeros(N-2,1)
for i = 1:N-2
    RHS(i) = p;
end
RHS(1) = RHS(1)-u(1)
RHS(end) = RHS(end)-u(end)


% Stiffness Matrix
stiffness = -2*eye(N-2,N-2);
for i = 1:N-3
    if i<N-2
        stiffness(i,i+1) = 1;
    end
    if i>1
        stiffness (i,i-1) = 1;
    end
   end

u_unknowns = stiffness\RHS;
u(2:end-1) = u_unknowns;

plot(x,u)
```

Comment: Hi! On the line `RHS(i) = p`, `p` is a vector, that you try to assign to a single entry in the vector `RHS`

Comment: Just change **line 38**, `RHS(i) = p`, to this `RHS(i) = p(i+1);`, does that work?